# Print result is different in the array function

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with the array PHP function, below is my first sample code:

```html
$country = array(
            "Holland" => "David",
            "England" => "Holly"
        );
print_r ($country);
```

This is the result `Array ( [Holland] => David [England] => Holly )`

I want to ask, is possible to make the array data become variables? For second example like below the sample code, I want to store the data in the variable `$data` the put inside the array.:

```html
$data = '"Holland" => "David","England" => "Holly"';
$country = array($data);
        print_r ($country);
```

But this result is shown me like this: `Array ( [0] => "Holland" => "David","England" => "Holly" )`

May I know these two conditions why the results are not the same? Actually, I want the two conditions can get the same results, which is `Array ( [Holland] => David [England] => Holly )`.

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You mean Holland and England will become variables and David & Holly will be the values within it ?

Comment: _“May I know these two conditions why the results are not the same?”_ - because in the first version you are writing _code_, whereas in the second, it is just _data_. _“is possible to make the array data become variables?”_ - in this way, not without `eval` (evil!) or a custom parser. You should rather use a data format like JSON for stuff like this.

Comment: @John Doe Yes. Will become variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Code.

```
<?php
$country = array(
    "Holland" => "David",
    "England" => "Holly"
);
foreach ($country as $index => $value)
{
    $$index = $value;
}
?>
```

Now, Holland & England are two variables. You can use them using $Holland etc.

**A syntax such as $$variable is called Variable Variable. Actually The inner $ resolves the a variable to a string, and the outer one resolves a variable by that string.**

Comment: Thanks. How to put these "Holland" => "David","England" => "Holly" into variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract elements from an associative array such that the keys become variable names and values become the value of that variable you can use [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```php
extract($country);
```

To check what changed you can do

```php
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

Explanation on why the below does not work

```
$data = '"Holland" => "David","England" => "Holly"';
```

When you enclose the above in single quotes `'` php would recognise it as a string. And php will parse a string as a string and not as an array.

Do note it is not enough to create a string with the same syntax as the code and expect php to parse it as code. The codes will work if you do this

```
$data = ["Holland" => "David","England" => "Holly"];
```

However, now `$data` itself is an array.

A simple copy of an array can be made by using

```
$data = $country;
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is this thing called

> [Destructuring](https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php)

You can do it something like ["Holland" => $eolland, "England" => $england] = $country;

And now you have your array elements inside the variables.

Go read the article above if you want more information about this because it gets really useful (especially in unit tests usind data provders from my experience).